# NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID : TSLint (ng add @angular-eslint/schematics)

Tags: node.js, angular, lint

I am upgrading my Angular 10 application to Angular 13. I did well with other compatibilities of dependencies. The project is compiling and working fine. Now the time for TSLint I tried to update the lint with the below command.

```
ng add @angular-eslint/schematics
```

But getting the error message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID
```

Comment: angular-eslint does not have a stable version which supports Angular 13 yet, see this GitHub issue: https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/issues/790

Comment: I've been running into same issues with same versions today (v10 to v13). So far I've got it to install by deleting package lock and node_modules then running ng add @angular-eslint/schematics@next

Answer (score 35):

For eslint:

```
ng add @angular-eslint/schematics@12 #for angular 12

ng add @angular-eslint/schematics@13 #for angular 13

ng add @angular-eslint/schematics@14 #for angular 14
```

Comment: You can specify more, with `@14.2.0`, for example, these days. (but `@14.2.10` will be excessive: it won't match at this level of detail).

Answer (score 26):

```
ng add @angular-eslint/schematics@next
```

This worked for me
[github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/issues/790](http://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/issues/790).

Comment: This worked for me when upgrading to Angular 14. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I solved the problem downgrading angular cli version to 12

[image]

Answer (score 8):

It seams that a lot of packages throw this error. I had the same error when adding NgRx store. It looks like that installing the **latest** version of the packages usually fix the issue:

```
ng add package_name/@latest
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me with @angular/pwa: ```ng add @angular/pwa@latest --project MyProjectName```. The project is using Angular 14.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue in **Angular 14, IONIC 6** project while generating pages/components . And resolved it by **replacing id with $id manually** on following paths:

1. node_modules > @Ionic > angular-toolkit > schematics > page > schema.json > replace id with $id on line 3.
2. node_modules > @Ionic > angular-toolkit > schematics > component > schema.json > replace id with $id on line 3.

Comment: doing `npm i @ionic/angular-toolkit@latest --save-dev` solved this for me with angular@16 and Ionic@6

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I could fix it by by upgrading angular/universal to the same version as my angular version is.

Answer (score 3):

For me, just by adding the most current version, did it:

```
ng add @angular/pwa@15.0.4
```

[The list of versions are here available](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/pwa?activeTab=versions).

Answer (score 2):

It appear while I'm using angular 14, after upgrading angular 15(before that reinstalling angular cli) resolve problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Install manually the version of [@angular/pwa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/pwa?activeTab=versions) corresponding to your version of angular and then run "ng add @angular/pwa"

Answer (score 0):

I had a conflict where the third-party package I was using had been replaced by an official one, but for some reason I had both of them in my package.json file The real issue though was that the angular.json file was using the older builder instead of the newer one.
I removed the package and used `ng add` to add the new package via its schematic, and after that things started working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your versions match `ng version`

Mine was:

```
Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1100.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.8
@angular-devkit/core            11.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.8 (cli-only)
@angular/cli                    15.2.8
@nguniversal/builders           11.0.1
@nguniversal/express-engine     15.2.1
@schematics/angular             15.2.8 (cli-only)
rxjs                            7.5.0
typescript                      4.9.5
```

So you see, `@angular-devkit/architect` needed to be `0.15` and `@nguniversal/builders` needed to be on 15 as well in my case.

From this github [post](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/issues/790#issuecomment-1422223100):

1. Remove your node_modules and delete your lock file and rebuild it with a fresh install
2. Force clean your global npm cache (npm clear cache --force)
3. delete your npx cache (on a mac that is rm -rf ~/.npm/_npx)

The first step was sufficient for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your versions match `ng version`

In my case, I was working with angular universal for server-side rendering.

My angular version was 17 which means that this `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` will be dropped in favor of this `ng add @angular/ssr`