# An unhandled exception occurred: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID

Tags: angular, google-cloud-functions, angular-universal, angular13

When running `ng deploy` I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID
See "C:\Users\theoh\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-Nv0wMh\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The full log of the error is the following:

```
[error] Error: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID
    at Object.code (D:\code\brain-consulting\bbc\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\vocabularies\core\id.js:6:15)
    at keywordCode (D:\code\brain-consulting\bbc\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\validate\index.js:454:13)
    at D:\code\brain-consulting\bbc\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\validate\index.js:222:17
    at CodeGen.code (D:\code\brain-consulting\bbc\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\codegen\index.js:439:13)
    at CodeGen.block (D:\code\brain-consulting\bbc\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\codegen\index.js:568:18)
    at iterateKeywords (D:\code\brain-consulting\bbc\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\validate\index.js:219:9)
    at groupKeywords (D:\code\brain-consulting\bbc\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\validate\index.js:208:13)
    at D:\code\brain-consulting\bbc\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\validate\index.js:192:13
    at CodeGen.code (D:\code\brain-consulting\bbc\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\codegen\index.js:439:13)
    at CodeGen.block (D:\code\brain-consulting\bbc\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\codegen\index.js:568:18)
```

I tried `ng add @angular-eslint/schematics@next` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69895552/not-supported-keyword-id-use-id-for-schema-id-tslint-ng-add-angular-e) but it did not work. The versions I use are the following:

```
Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1300.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.0.3
@angular-devkit/core            13.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.0.3
@angular/cli                    13.0.3
@angular/fire                   7.0.2
@nguniversal/builders           13.0.1
@nguniversal/express-engine     13.0.1
@schematics/angular             13.0.3
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.4.4
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. In my case, it was caused by @angular-builders/custom-webpack that was not updated during ng update. So manually updating it from version 10.0.1 to ^13.0.0 solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my angular project when I am trying to create a service like this

```
ng g s folder-name/folder-name/service-name
```

I got this error from angular cli

```
An unhandled exception occurred: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID
See "/private/var/folders/fw/5mkxql_j6c33ssny9wj1w1g80000gn/T/ng-ixUrL3/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Therefore I run CLI commands without using alias `s - services` like this : Used full name

```
ng generate service folder-name/folder-name/service-name
```

Above again in the CLI command works for me. Hope this trick helps you as well.

Comment: Yes it works for me too.. but something is wrong. The short version like "ng g c something" should work :(

Comment: Yes, that's true. short version should work. I'm trying to find why it is not working. May be it is Angular CLI issue or bug.

Comment: I found my bug - I use a state management package called Akita - it comes with its own cli commands - I upgraded it and the problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the package-lock file "if its safe to do so" & the node modules folder. then in the package.json file change
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0" to "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0"
Then hit npm install.
it worked for me

Comment: there are commands for updating/upgrading packages

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done to solve this issue:

- remove package-lock.json
- npm install
- npm update