# The ngx-deploy-ftp mod does not work in the new version of Angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, deployment, ftp, console

the other day I updated my application from angular 12 to version 13, everything was updated, but the ngx-deploy-ftp module does not want to work, and the compilation gives an error:

```
➜ newhope git:(master) ng deploy newhope
An unhandled exception occurred: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID
See "/private/var/folders/q2/yw06gtw90td1d0hdm0l8d6cm0000gn/T/ng-lJNBeX/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

When installing packages, I install via npm install --legacy-peer-deps, because there are conflicts in the packages, but this does not affect the performance:

```
npm ERR! @ angular / cdk @ "^ 13.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @ angular / cdk @ "^ 12.0.0" from @ angular / flex-layout @ 12.0.0-beta.35
npm ERR! node_modules / @ angular / flex-layout
npm ERR! @ angular / flex-layout @ "^ 12.0.0-beta.35" from the root project
```

What can you tell me how to solve it, I tried to fix it by installing additional packages, as indicated in the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69895552/not-supported-keyword-id-use-id-for-schema-id-tslint-ng-add-angular-e)