# Angular schematics exception: "NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID"

Tags: angular, exception, angular-cli, package.json, angular-schematics

I have a custom schematic that won't apply to a new project... I also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69895552/not-supported-keyword-id-use-id-for-schema-id-tslint-ng-add-angular-e) but I couldn't make it work...

My **main workspace** runs with this configuration:

```
Angular CLI: 13.2.3
Node: 16.13.0
Package Manager: npm 7.24.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.2.2
... core

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1302.3 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         11.2.18
@angular-devkit/schematics   11.2.18
@schematics/angular          13.2.3 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.1102.18
```

And my **project** with this:

```
Angular CLI: 13.2.3
Node: 16.13.0
Package Manager: npm 7.24.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.2.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router     

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------  
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1302.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.2.3
@angular-devkit/core            13.2.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.2.3
@angular/cli                    13.2.3
@schematics/angular             13.2.3
rxjs                            7.5.4
typescript                      4.5.5
```

Inside my workspace i can make a new project with no problems; then i move inside it and when I run the command `ng g project-template-13:project-template-13` (my custom schematic) the following exception is thrown:

```
[error] Error: Collection "project-template-13" cannot be resolved.
at SchematicEngineHost.resolve (C:\Users\user\workspace\my-project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\node-module-engine-host.js:75:19)
at SchematicEngineHost._resolveCollectionPath (C:\Users\user\workspace\my-project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\node-module-engine-host.js:80:37)
at SchematicEngineHost.createCollectionDescription (C:\Users\user\workspace\my-project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\file-system-engine-host-base.js:118:27)
at SchematicEngine._createCollectionDescription (C:\Users\user\workspace\my-project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\engine\engine.js:162:40)
at SchematicEngine.createCollection (C:\Users\user\workspace\my-project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\engine\engine.js:155:43)
at GenerateCommand.getCollection (C:\Users\user\workspace\my-project\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\schematic-command.js:143:35)
at GenerateCommand.initialize (C:\Users\user\workspace\my-project\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\schematic-command.js:62:37)
at async GenerateCommand.initialize (C:\Users\user\workspace\my-project\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\generate-impl.js:20:9)
at async GenerateCommand.validateAndRun (C:\Users\user\workspace\my-project\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command.js:121:22)
at async runCommand (C:\Users\user\workspace\my-project\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:224:24)
```

I tried **downgrading** to angular 12 as said in the question mentioned above, but it doesn't seem to work.
Can someone help me with this?

**P.s.** I'll provide additional information if needed

Answer (score 1):

I found out that there were 2 typos... The first one in one function of my schematics, the other one in the schema.json where i had `"id": "ProjectTemplateSchema"` instead of `"$id": "ProjectTemplateSchema"`

Answer (score 0):

try doing ng update on the main workspace cause the issue is probably caused by version mismatch. These packages:

```
@angular-devkit/core         11.2.18
@angular-devkit/schematics   11.2.18
```

should become thirteen.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone else when using nx I had to manually update the angular.json of an existing library build using ng-packagr from "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr" to "@nrwl/angular:ng-packagr-lite". Then remove the dependency @angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr from my project.