# Angular 16 : An unhandled exception occurred: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 16, Node 18.17, and npm 10.2.5. When creating a new component, I get the following error message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID. See "C:\Users\DAIKIM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-YZkQDl\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I have updated the different versions, deleted the node_modules, and reinstalled them, as well as the package lock.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID : TSLint (ng add @angular-eslint/schematics)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69895552/not-supported-keyword-id-use-id-for-schema-id-tslint-ng-add-angular-e)